# SQL: Add multiple columns from another dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset `train` that is structured like so

```
+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+                                  
|  a|  b|  c|aml_freq_a|aml_freq_b|aml_freq_c|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  v|  l|  l|        56|        42|        29|
|  u|  g|  l|        47|        46|        29|
|  s|  g|  l|        28|        46|        29|
|  v|  m|  l|        56|        33|        29|
|  h|  m|  l|        44|        33|        29|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

The `aml_freq_a`, `aml_freq_b` and `aml_freq_c` columns are frequencies of corresponding entries in the `a, b` and `c` column. For example, the value `56` under `aml_freq_a` is basically the count/frequency of the number of times `v` has occurred in column `a`. Similarly for `b` and `c`.

I have another dataset, called `test`, which has only the `a, b` and `c` columns,

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  w|  j|  c|
|  a|  g|  w|
|  s|  d|  i|
|  g|  j|  r|
|  r|  b|  u|
+---+---+---+
```

I need to add the `aml_freq_a`, `aml_freq_b` and `aml_freq_c` columns to it. To do this, I used subqueries that join the `test` and `train` on column `a` and then selects the `aml_freq_a` column. I wrote two more subqueries for `b` and `c`. This is how my query looks

```
SELECT test.*, 
       (SELECT aml_freq_a 
        FROM   test 
               LEFT JOIN train 
                      ON test.a = train.a), 
       (SELECT aml_freq_b 
        FROM   test 
               LEFT JOIN train 
                      ON test.b = train.b), 
       (SELECT aml_freq_c 
        FROM   test 
               LEFT JOIN train 
                      ON test.c = train.c) 
FROM   test
```

But when I run this, I get the following error

```
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I didn't understand this error. Since I am doing a `left join` with `test` as the left, how can there be more rows?

Any direction would be great.

*PS: I read the other posts about the same issue, but the way they reached this error is different from what I am doing and the solutions there haven't helped me much.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need three joins here, one for each of the frequency columns in the `train` table:

```
SELECT
    t.a,
    t.b,
    t.c,
    tr1.aml_freq_a,
    tr2.aml_freq_b,
    tr3.aml_freq_c
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN train tr1
    ON t.a = tr1.a
LEFT JOIN train tr2
    ON t.b = tr2.b
LEFT JOIN train tr3
    ON t.c = tr3.c
```

**Edit:**

If you wanted to go with your current approach, then something along these lines might work:

```
SELECT
    t.*, 
   (SELECT aml_freq_a FROM train tr WHERE t.a = tr.a) aml_freq_a,
   (SELECT aml_freq_b FROM train tr WHERE t.b = tr.b) aml_freq_b,
   (SELECT aml_freq_c FROM train tr WHERE t.c = tr.c) aml_freq_c
FROM test t;
```

I say *might*, because those subqueries would have to *always* return a single value to avoid error.  And even if this works, the join approach I gave should outperform it.

Comment: I may sound like an idiot but can you tell me what is the difference between what you provided and I wrote. It looks the same to me (obviously it isn't). I am also selecting the same variables, performing the same joins. so why does yours work?

Comment: @ClockSlave Actually our queries are completely different.  You are trying to select an entire column from `train` for every row in `test`.  Superficially, they look similar, but they are doing very different things.